# ssh local port forwarding with 2 servers

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding

I used to do the local port forwarding like below to access VNC server from local:

```
ssh -v -N -L 5902:target_server:5902 me@jump_host1
```

However, there is some change to my workplace that we cannot directly connect to `jump_host1` using WiFi: we have to connect to another server `guard` and then connect to `jump_host1` from `guard`.

Now, my question is how can I do the port forwarding in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Already been answered https://superuser.com/questions/96489/an-ssh-tunnel-via-multiple-hops

Comment: @marc I don't think so. In my case, there are 4 servers involved: my local, guard, jump_host1, target_server. If so, please shed lights on how I can adapt the answer there to my case. Tried all three options in the answer. None of them works for me.

Comment: Having 3, 4 or 10 involved, doesn't change the fact of using the same explained principle as a foundation to solve the problem.

Comment: @marc I see your point. However, my question is more on how the 4th server fit in the solution. Principle is good but I'd like to see more examples. Thanks! I have no interest with `localhost2` mentioned in the solution because it will be a jump host in my case.

Comment: In any case I would just use the **ProxyJump** directive, enabling you to add easily as much intermediaries as you like: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts

Comment: @marc The solution you mention only works for OpenSSH 7.3 and above. But I only have OpenSSH 6.2

Comment: for older ssh: [Replace ProxyJump in ~/.ssh/config](https://superuser.com/questions/1253960/replace-proxyjump-in-ssh-config)

Comment: As A.B commented, you can replace the ProxyJump directive by using the older method `ProxyCommand ssh SSH_CONFIG_DEFINED_PROXY -W %h:%p`